# How to get a collection from firestore with exception of one list

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore to store my data and I want to fetch a collection of users from my db except one (Current User). How can I do this.

This is the image of my db

[image]

Here I want to fetch all users except the one with id 'gi3oGztVrKQoiEHxFv28TAQpxah2'

The code I am currently using is

`this.donorCollection = this.fireStore.collection<any>('users').valueChanges();
console.log(this.donorCollection);
this.donorCollection.subscribe(data => console.log(data) );`

Which returns all users. The reason for this specific task is that my current user always updates his/her db whenever his/her position changes. Therefore if I applied `valuechanges()` to the current collection it will always give new value as current user is updating his/her postion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by refering this -

```
Queries with a != clause. In this case, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example, although the query clause where("age", "!=", "30") is not supported, you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause where("age", "<", "30") and one with the clause where("age", ">", 30).
```

Since my `phone` field is unique . I solved this by calling query as follows

```
this.donorCollectionLR = this.fireStore.collection<any>('users', ref =>
      ref.where('phone', '<', '8086960113')).valueChanges();
      this.donorCollectionLR.subscribe(data =>{
        this.donorCollectionGR = this.fireStore.collection<any>('users', ref =>
        ref.where('phone', '>', '8086960113')).valueChanges();
        this.donorCollectionGR.subscribe(data2 =>{
          data2=data2.concat(data);
          observer.next(data2)
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't exclude documents with a Firestore query.  With Firestore queries, you specify all the conditions that must be true (where x and y and z, etc).

That said, it's trivial and inexpensive to filter the results of the query on the client if all you want to do is exclude one document.

Comment: Here phone field is unique , Is there any way to filter it out using 'phone' field?

Comment: Please read my answer again - "You can't exclude documents with a Firestore query".

Answer (score 0):

Just filter from the collection as follows,

```
this.donorCollection.subscribe((data) => {
 this.users = data.filter(person => person.id != 'gi3oGztVrKQoiEHxFv28TAQpxah2');
 console.log(this.users) ;
});
```